# How to pass data from one view to another view in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to pass one array from first view to second view in react native. So how can I achieve this in react native ? For navigation I am using '**react-navigation**'.

```
this.navigation.navigateWithDebounce('BlaBlaView', {title: 'BlaBla View'}).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your'e using react-navigation's `naviagte`. you can pass the parameters as the second parameter, for instance:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(`ROUTE_NAME`, { params: 'param value' });
```

And then, within the view you navigated to you can access it:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { param } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer....Thanks..:)  Just add the 'param' after the 'params'......this.props.navigation.state.params.param